# Counterexamples to Brouwer's fixed point theorem for the closed unit ball in Banach space

Tags: general-topology, fixed-point-theorems

Brouwer fixed point theorem states that for any compact convex set $X$, a continuous mapping from $X$ to $X$ has at least one fixed point.

Brouwer fixed point theorem applies in particular on the close unit ball of a finite dimensional space.

Do you have counterexample(s) where Brouwer fixed point theorem does not hold on the close unit ball of a Banach space (of infinite dimension)?

*Note: this question is a refinement of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1337161/brouwer-fixed-point-theorem-infinite-dimension) which was put on hold.*

Comment: Does the fact that in infinite dimension the close unit ball is not compact ensure the fact that Brouwer fixed point theorem cannot be applied ? In that case there will be a lot of counterexample

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A comment in the other question mentioned that the wiki page for [the Brouwer Fixed Point Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem#Generalizations) had a counterexample for the Hilbert space $\ell^2$.  I'll adapt the statement there to $\ell^p$ where $p < \infty$ so you can compare the two:

> In the Banach space $\ell^p$ of $p$-norm summable real (or complex) sequences, consider the map $f : \ell^p → \ell^p$ which sends a sequence $x_n$ from the closed unit ball of $\ell^p$ to the sequence $y_n$ defined by
>
> $$y_0=\sqrt[p]{1-\|x\|_p^p} \,\,\textrm{ and } \,\, y_n=x_{n-1} \textrm{ for } n\geq 1$$
>
> It is not difficult to check that this map is continuous, has its image in the unit sphere of $\ell^p$, but does not have a fixed point.

Comment: Thanks. I imagine that you meant $y_0=\sqrt[p]{1-\|x\|_p^p}$

Comment: Yes, I did.  Thanks.